# Gnuplot: Store plot area dimensions for later use

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to store the dimensions of the plotting space in gnuplot?  I don't mean the whole canvas, rather, the area within the plotting frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a `plot` command several gnuplot-defined variables `GPVAL_*` are available (type `show variables all`) to see the values. Some of them can be used to get the margins of the previous plot:

```
plot sin(x)
TSCALE = 1.0
LMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE)
RMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE)
TMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE)
BMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE)
```

To restore the margins later, use

```
set lmargin at screen LMARGIN
set rmargin at screen RMARGIN
set tmargin at screen TMARGIN
set bmargin at screen BMARGIN
```

`TSCALE` is a factor, which is terminal-dependent, because the `GPVAL_TERM_*MIN` and `GPVAL_TERM_*MAX` are scaled internally by an oversampling factor, but the `GPVAL_TERM_*SIZE` values are not (at least with 4.6.0, 4.6.3 and 4.7 (2013-09-23)). For `pdfcairo` this value must be `20`, while for `wxt` it is `1`. A rather complete check for different terminals is:

```
if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'pdfcairo' || \
    GPVAL_TERM eq 'cairolatex' || \
    GPVAL_TERM eq 'pngcairo' || \
    (GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript' && strstrt(GPVAL_TERMOPTIONS, 'eps ') == 1)) {
        TSCALE = 20.0
} else {
    if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'svg' || GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript') {
        TSCALE = 10.0
    } else {    
        TSCALE = 1.0
    }   
}
```

Since gnuplot 5.0 a separate variable `GPVAL_TERM_SCALE` is available which already contains the appropriate value for the selected terminal and make this complex check obsolete.

### Automating

There are many ways to automate this. You can e.g. write these definitions in strings and just call `eval` on them when you need them:

```
save_margins = 'TSCALE = 1.0;'\
               'LMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE);'.\
               'RMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE);'.\
               'TMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE);'.\
               'BMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE);'
plot sin(x)
eval(save_margins)
print LMARGIN
```

and accordingly

```
restore_margins = 'set lmargin at screen LMARGIN;'.\
                  'set rmargin at screen RMARGIN;'.\
                  'set tmargin at screen TMARGIN;'.\
                  'set bmargin at screen BMARGIN'
eval(restore_margins)
```

### Universal usage

To use these features as universal as possible, just put the following in a script e.g. `fixed-margins.gp`:

```
save_margins = 'LMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE);'.\
               'RMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_XMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE);'.\
               'TMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE);'.\
               'BMARGIN = TSCALE*GPVAL_TERM_YMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE);'
restore_margins = 'set lmargin at screen LMARGIN;'.\
                  'set rmargin at screen RMARGIN;'.\
                  'set tmargin at screen TMARGIN;'.\
                  'set bmargin at screen BMARGIN;'
set_fixed_margins = save_margins . restore_margins

if (exists('GPVAL_TERM_SCALE')) {
    TSCALE = GPVAL_TERM_SCALE
} else {
    if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'pdfcairo' || \
        GPVAL_TERM eq 'cairolatex' || \
        GPVAL_TERM eq 'pngcairo' || \
        (GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript' && strstrt(GPVAL_TERMOPTIONS, 'eps ') == 1)) {
            TSCALE = 20.0
    } else {
        if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'svg' || GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript') {
            TSCALE = 10.0
        } else {    
            TSCALE = 1.0
        }   
    }
}
```

To use this feature, just `load` the script after having set the terminal, and then `eval` the margin string at the appropriate positions in the plot:

```
set terminal ...
load 'fixed-margins.gp'

set multiplot
plot sin(x)
eval(set_fixed_margins)
....
```

Comment: gnuplot 4.4 introduced `GPVAL_TERM_*` variables. In gnuplot 5.0 there is also `GPVAL_TERM_SCALE`. I can confirm for pdfcairo `GPVAL_TERM_SCALE = 20` and for postscript `GPVAL_TERM_SCALE = 10`.

Comment: @Hotschke Yes, thanks for the addition. I already used this variable in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28888288/2604213 :) I updated the script for universal usage to use this variable, if available.