# Conversion between gnuplot's coordinates systems

Tags: gnuplot

### TL;DR

Is there a way to align corners of different plots in a multiplot setup?

Is there a way to convert `axis` coordinates to `screen` coordinates?

### Detailed explanation

I'm trying to layout a quite complicated canvas with gnuplot. To achieve what I want, I need to stack different plots on each other exactly.

I did something like :

```
reset;
set samples 20;
set xrange [-pi:pi]; set yrange [-2:1];
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y";
unset key

set multiplot;
plot cos(x) w lp;
plot 2*cos(x+pi) w lp;
unset multiplot;
```

However, some components like the label, tics and borders are drawn twice. Then, when I do this with the `cairolatex` terminal the result is not as clear as if I don't stack plots.

Thus, I would like to draw these components for the first plot and then unset labels, tics and borders for the subsequent ones as shown in the snippet below:

```
set multiplot;
plot cos(x) w lp;

set border ls 4; # Just to distinguish it
unset xlabel; unset ylabel;
unset tics;
plot 2*cos(x+pi) w lp;
unset multiplot;
```

This generate an image where the next plots are not aligned (on left and bottom) with the first one, as no space is taken by the labels and tics.

[image: Not aligned borders]

To address this issue, I need to set the origin and size of the next plots manually. The bottom left corners must be aligned.

From the gnuplot documentation, it is possible the get the `screen` coordinated of an `(X,Y) axis` coordinate using:

```
GRAPH_X = (X - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN)
GRAPH_Y = (Y - GPVAL_Y_MIN) / (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)
SCREEN_X = GPVAL_TERM_XMIN + GRAPH_X * (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)
SCREEN_Y = GPVAL_TERM_YMIN + GRAPH_Y * (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)
FRAC_X = SCREEN_X * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE
FRAC_Y = SCREEN_Y * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE
```

As we are trying to align the bottom left corner, `(X,Y) == (GPVAL_X_MIN, GPVAL_Y_MIN)`. Thus, `GRAPH_* = 0` and `SCREEN_(*) = GPVAL_TERM_\1MIN`. Thus:

```
# Multiply by 1.0 to promote variables to floats
FRAC_X = 1.0 * GPVAL_TERM_XMIN * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE
FRAC_Y = 1.0 * GPVAL_TERM_YMIN * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE
```

Resulting snippet:

```
set multiplot;
plot cos(x) w lp;

FRAC_X = 1.0 * GPVAL_TERM_XMIN * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE;
FRAC_Y = 1.0 * GPVAL_TERM_YMIN * GPVAL_TERM_SCALE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE;
set origin FRAC_X, FRAC_Y;

set border ls 4; # Just to distinguish it
unset xlabel; unset ylabel;
unset tics;
plot 2*cos(x+pi) w lp;
unset multiplot;
```

But as you can see, resulting plot is not better...

[image: Origin not matching]

By the way, I did not find how to define the `size` to align the top right corners.

#### Questions

What is wrong with the origin computation? How to align top right corner as well?

Kind regards,

Alexis.

Comment: Why do you need to overlap the two plots, for your given example you could simply use `plot cos(x) w lp, 2*cos(x+pi) w lp`

Comment: For this simple example, for sure your answer is the right way to do it. However my problem is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43996765/4373898 which need overlapping plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the margins to keep the automatic size after the first plot as follows (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132068/2604213):

```
fix_margins = 'set margins '.\
    'screen GPVAL_TERM_SCALE * GPVAL_TERM_XMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE), '.\
    'screen GPVAL_TERM_SCALE * GPVAL_TERM_XMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE), '.\
    'screen GPVAL_TERM_SCALE * GPVAL_TERM_YMIN/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE), '.\
    'screen GPVAL_TERM_SCALE * GPVAL_TERM_YMAX/(1.0*GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE)'

set samples 20
set xrange [-pi:pi]; set yrange [-2:1]
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y"
unset key

set multiplot
plot cos(x) w lp
eval(fix_margins)
unset tics; unset xlabel; unset ylabel
plot 2*cos(x+pi) w lp
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems even easier than what I proposed! However plots do not superpose exactly, there is something like 1 or 2 pixels of difference. I suppose that it is due to some floating point approximation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve an exact overlap, I think that an option would be to adjust the `margin` manually:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

eps_h = 0.1
eps_w = 0.1

set multiplot
unset key

set lmargin at screen 2*eps_w
set tmargin at screen 1 - eps_h
set rmargin at screen 1 - eps_w
set bmargin at screen eps_h

plot cos(x) w lp lc rgb 'dark-red'

set border ls 4;
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset tics

plot 2*cos(x+pi) w lp lc rgb 'royalblue'
```

which gives:
[image]